# Prevent re-targeting of events on LWC

Tags: salesforce-lightning

Not able to get the event's original source on LWC.

Hi,
We are migrating an Aura component to LWC. We have a USE CASE,  is being used in an iteration. 
On click of , we are showing . The data in  is dynamically retrieved based on record-id of . 
In Aura, this was fairly simple because when  fires an event, we can inject the data through method from grand parent to event.getSource().
But in LWC, the event is getting re-targeted on every parent-level bubbling. So finally event.target is returning the  instead of .
Hence we are not able to inject data dynamically through event. What is the best approach for this scenario?

```
<!--c-todo-app>
<c-todo-item>
    <div>
        <!--Dynamic Iteration--Starts>
        <c-todo-line-item>
            <c-sub-item>
        <c-todo-line-item>
            <c-subitem>
       -- 
        ...
        ...
        ...
        --
        <c-todo-line-item>
            <c-subitem>
        <!--Dynamic Iteration--Ends>
    </div>
</c-todo-item>
```

Event.target OR event.currentTarget should give the source component but instead gives the top-most component below the handling component. In above example- event is fired in  and handled in . Component returned is  BUT we need